# VBA Function to return the value only when File can be opened without any error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an Excel VBA code to Check how many files in a folder are corrupt.
A folder named as 'Folder' in 'E' drive has these pdf files.

In my workbook; Column A of **Sheet1** has fileNames from this folder.
I have a code which loops through the `filesNames` from column A and opens those.

**My objective is** : If the file can be opened; then don't print anything in the adjacent cell (of column B) else print as '`Corrupt`'.

But, when I run this VBA code; as each time loop goes to the Function OpenPDFPage(), it do not print anything in the adjacent cell of column B.
(I want to print it only when the file is corrupt and I get message box saying "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired")

Can I know what change I've to make to the Function OpenPDFPage() so that, when there is a corrupt file (or the file which can't be opened) in folder; then only code will print "corrupt" in the adjacent cell of column B.

The code is as below:

```
Option Explicit
    
Function OpenPDFPage(PDFPath As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Error_OpenPDFPage
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    OpenPDFPage = True

    Exit_OpenPDFPage:
    Exit Function

    Error_OpenPDFPage:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
    OpenPDFPage = False
    Resume Exit_OpenPDFPage

End Function
    
Sub Test()
        
        Dim MyFolder As String
        Dim filename As Range
        Dim MyFile As String
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
        MyFolder = "E:\Folder"
        For Each filename In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    
        MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & filename
    
        If OpenPDFPage(MyFile) = True Then
        'Do Nothing
        Else
        filename.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Corrupt"
        End If              
    
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your function `OpenPDFPage` never returns true or false. So I guess it returns false by default. This example does what you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 can you try to understand it and use it and post back any questions?

Comment: Thank You Buddy.
I've edited my question, after going through it.
Now, `I'll work towards recording a macro which can parse/check the error msgBox while opening a PDF file.` <-- Is it the right way? 
Or `I need to write another code to check whether the file is open?`

Comment: For Timebeing I've written another macro which checks whether file is open and if it isn't open, it prints 'Corrupt' in adjacent cell of same row - Column B. :)

Comment: You're using "FollowHyperlink". Does this mean the file is on the internet? Or are these files in a drive somewhere? By Corrupt do you mean it doesn't open? I suggest you first remove the msgbox altogether and actually return the error message and write _that_ in the cell. Then afterwards you can analyse all the error messages and understand what you should do.

Comment: Files are in E Drive inside a `Folder`. By corrupt meant: `file is actually corrupt` or `Can't open with the current version of Adobe Reader`,  Okay.
I'll follow the instructions.
Thank u :)

Comment: OK. You'll need to find a file that you know is corrupt and test that your OpenPDFPage function returns false as expected. It might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another macro to the above; to check whether the file is opened; 
If it's not opened through previous macro, then am assuming it's corrupt;
and printing in adjacent cell of column B as 'Corrupt'.

```
Sub IsFileOpened()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim filename As Range
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    MyFolder = "E:\Folder"
    For Each filename In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & filename        
        If IsFileOpen(MyFile) = True Then
           ' Do Nothing
       Else
           filename.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Corrupt"
       End If
    Next
End Sub


   Function IsFileOpen(filename As String) As Boolean

       Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

       On Error Resume Next   
       filenum = FreeFile()   

       'Attempt to open the file and lock it.

       Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
       Close filenum          ' Close the file.
       errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
       On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

       ' Check to see which error occurred.
       Select Case errnum

           Case 0
               IsFileOpen = False

           Case 70
               IsFileOpen = True

           ' Another error occurred.
           'Case Else
               'Error errnum
       End Select
   End Function
```